# Error on UN-installation of SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 64 bit System

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to un-install **completely** SQL Server 2008 R2 from my 64bit system. When I tried to install, I experienced a common problem about "INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR" but I managed to install anyway. Now, I can't un-install.

I even tried cmd but when action is uninstall, it doesn't accept INSTALLSHAREDWOVDIR command.

Here is the error I got;

> The **INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR** command line value is not valid. Please ensure
>   the specified path is valid and
>   different than the **INSTALLSHAREDDIR**
>   path.

Note that, this error is NOT for installation, it's for removal of SQL.
Regards

Comment: I think you can google this, as there are already lot of solutions provided by microsoft themselves about this problem

Comment: thank you @Karthik Ratnam for suggestion but when I first asked this question 4 months age, I wasn't able to find any article about this issue. There were lot's of articles for installation but unfortunately none for the un-installation.